# Register a default named registration

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Using Unity, you can register an interface so it resolves a type with some parameters, and you can also have named registration :

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, MyClass>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("Default"))
    );

container.RegisterType<IInterface, MyClass>(
    "Named First",
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("Named First"))
    );

container.RegisterType<IInterface, MyClass>(
    "Named Second",
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("Named Second"))
    );
```

Let's say I want my default registration do the same thing as "Named Second" registration. I could could do that :

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, MyClass>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("Named Second"))
    );
```

Is there a way to have the default (unnamed?) registration **points** towards the second named registration, instead of replicating the whole thing? Something like :

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, IInterface("Named Second")>(); // Doesn't work.
```

In the example, it's only a constructor with one parameter, but let's say the constructor takes 8 interfaces, 2 InjectionProperties and an InjectionMethod, you wouldn't want to duplicate that, risking desynchronisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface>( new InjectionFactory(
   c => c.Resolve<IInterface>( "Named Second" ) ) );
```

Haven't tested that but it should do just what you need.

Comment: Looks sound. I was afraid of resolving the interface at "registering time", but I don't know why I didn't think of using a lambda expression. I'll test it tomorrow, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work!